# cmder SSL verification - how to add to local store?

Tags: ssl, drupal, cmder

I am trying to install Drupal Vm via Cmder.
When I run 'Vagrant up;' command I get the following error:

```
Installing plugin vagrant-vbguest
**ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Root CA/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com to your local trusted store**
Vagrant failed to load a configured plugin source. This can be caused
by a variety of issues including: transient connectivity issues, proxy
filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source, or a configured
plugin source not responding correctly. Please review the error message
below to help resolve the issue:

  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://rubygems.org/
```

How to add "/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Root CA/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com" to my local trusted store ? Any help ?

Comment: Ever make progress on this?